# How to select all rows, which have any element of array of elements

Tags: postgresql

I have table accounts, which has column tickers_set. Tickers_set is a type of `text[]`, so it's just a collections of tickers.

E.g.

```
account| tickers_set
1      | {'aapl', 'f'}
2      | {'gazp', 'lkoh', 'f'}
```

If I want to find all accounts, which have ticker 'f', I would use select

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE 'f' = ANY(tickers_set);
```

But what should I do when I want to select all accounts, which have any of elements in array? Say I want to find all accounts with tickers 'f' AND 'gazp'.

It should be something like intersection select

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ['f', 'gazp'] = ANY(tickers_set);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) operator is for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
WHERE tickers_set @> array['f', 'gazp'];
```

If you want to find those that have *at least* one of the elements, you can use the overlaps operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
WHERE tickers_set && array['f', 'gazp'];
```